# Sitecore publishes entire content tree

Tags: sitecore, publishing

We are having an issue with Sitecore where smart publishes are being fired and we are not able to determine what is causing these to fire and who is firing them. The logs show that the smart publish is fired with 'children:false' option everytime by a user. But when I view publishes in the 'Publishing Status Manager' module, we see the entire site getting smart published. The site takes 10-15 minutes to publish the entire tree.

The module also shows the username against the publish but when we talked to those users, it turns out that they did not fire a smart publish for the site. Usually, they fire off incremental publishes.

There is also a scheduled publish that runs every 15 minutes which does an incremental publish.

Has anybody experienced this issue? Could the 'Publishing Status Manager' be causing this issue or an accidental configuration change be causing it?

Any tips/hints/suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is an issue with the Sitecore install where incremental publish is publishing child items and causing it to take forever. Sitecore support has provided a fix for it. This is not a known problem with Sitecore.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help, we had an issue with incremental publishes done through the API doing smart publishes instead.

Calling a incremental publish with the following code:

```
PublishAgent myPublish = new PublishAgent("master", "web", "incremental", "en");
myPublish.Run();
```

Was causing a smart publish instead.

Eventually we came across this:

```
Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
Sitecore.Data.Database[] targets = {Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web")};
Sitecore.Publishing.PublishManager.PublishIncremental(master, targets, master.Languages);
```

Which seemed to work correctly.

A cavet to this is that this was quite a while ago and I believe the site was on 5.3 so things might well be different these days.

Comment: The version we are using is 6.5. I have only one place in code that's doing an item publish without any children. It's a smart publish. Not sure if the suggestion you made would apply to our instance but thanks!